# Jquery Template data (Decimal datatype) adds Zero at end - Why?

Tags: jquery, templates, decimal

Can anyone tell me why my "Id" always gets a zero added at the end? and how to fix that?

http://jsfiddle.net/55u9M/13/

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr id='${Id}'>${Id}</tr>
</script>

<div id="tblMyTable"></div>


$(document).ready(function(){

 var test = [
  { Id: 43000796568231936 , ReleaseYear: "1998" },
  { Id: 43000796568231937 , ReleaseYear: "1999" },
  { Id: 43000796568231938 , ReleaseYear: "1976" }
  ];

    $("#myTemplate").tmpl(test).appendTo("#tblMyTable");

});
```

Comment: I have an ajax call that returns data in json format from an API.  My example does the same thing using my 'test' object. So perhaps I should modify the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a JS WTF...

```
alert(parseInt(43000796568231936));
```

It's changing your numbers to 43000796568231940.

This happens in Google Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

You can fix this by changing your integers to strings: http://jsfiddle.net/55u9M/16/

Change your JSON from:

```
var test = [
    { Id: 43000796568231936, ReleaseYear: "1998" },
    { Id: 43000796568231937, ReleaseYear: "1999" },
    { Id: 43000796568231938, ReleaseYear: "1976" }
];
```

To

```
var test = [
    { Id: '43000796568231936', ReleaseYear: "1998" },
    { Id: '43000796568231937', ReleaseYear: "1999" },
    { Id: '43000796568231938', ReleaseYear: "1976" }
];
```

Comment: Thanks McHerbie.  I tried the parseInt in my template but it didn't work.  ${parseInt(Id)}   I'm getting the data from an ajax call which is returning json data.  Can I convert the Id to a string in the loop before I commit it to the template?  http://jsfiddle.net/55u9M/20/

Comment: @mokumax, it's the JSON you need to update, not the template. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that works.  My problem is that I'm getting the data from an API.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to parse the JSON and do a replace but if that's the only way... doh!  Thanks for your responses.